# Compare fields from different rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

First off I am using SQL Server.

I am joining a table on itself like in the example below:

```
SELECT t.theDate,
    s.theDate,
    t.bitField,
    s.bitField,
    t.NAME,
    s.NAME
FROM table1 t
INNER JOIN table1 s ON t.NAME = s.NAME
```

If I take a random row (i.e. X) from the dataset produced.

Can I compare values in any field on row X to values in any field on row X-1 OR row X+1?

Example: I want to compare t.theDate on row 5  to s.theDate on row 4 or s.theDate on row 3.

Sample data looks like:

[image]

Desired results:

I want to pull all pairs of rows where the t.bitfield and s.bitfield are opposite and t.theDate and s.theDate are opposite.

From the image the would be row (3 & 4), (5 & 6), (7 & 8) ... etc.

I really appreciate any help!

Can it be done?

Comment: You need to specify an ordering...

Comment: wich dbms are you using?

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: @GordonLinoff is there enough information now? or do you need more?

Comment: @Fendec What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: @tarheel 12.0.4100.1

Comment: @Fendec One more question, what sorting are you using? Asking because without an ‘order by’ clause specified what is row 3 now may not be row 3 later. Which could change the result set, making it non-deterministic.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
WITH ts as (
      SELECT t.theDate as theDate1, s.theDate as theDate2,
             t.bitField as bitField1, s.bitField as bitField2,
             t.NAME  -- there is only one name
      FROM table1 t INNER JOIN
           table1 s
           ON t.NAME = s.NAME 
     )
SELECT ts.*
FROM ts
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM ts ts2
              WHERE ts2.name = ts.name AND
                    ts2.theDate1 = ts.theDate2 AND
                    ts2.theDate2 = ts.theDate1 AND
                    ts2.bitField1 = ts.bitField2 AND
                    ts2.bitField2 = ts.bitField1
              );
```

Comment: Can you explain what ts2 is?

Comment: @Fendec . . . It is now a table alias.  It was intended to be one previously, but the table itself was missing.

Answer (score 0):

**Varinant 1:** It looks like you would like to use `ranking function`.

```
if objcet_id('tempdb..#TmpOrderedTable') is not null drop table #TmpOrderedTable
select *, row_number(order by columnlist, (select 0)) rn
into #TmpOrderedTable
from table1 t

select * 
from #TmpOrderedTable t0
inner join #TmpOrderedTable tplus on t0.rn = tplus.rn + 1 -- next one
inner join #TmpOrderedTable tminus on t0.rn = tminus.rn - 1 -- previous one
```

**Varinant 2:**
To get scalar values you can use ranking function `lag` and `lead`. Or subquery.

**Varinant 3:**
You can use `selfjoin`, but you have to specify unique nonarbitary key if you don't want duplicates.

**Varinant 4:**
You can use `apply`.

Your question isn't too clear, so i hope it was your goal.